# How can I parse も in this sentence?

Tags: parsing, particle-も

I'm really confused by the role of も in this sentence:

> KONAMIから許諾を得ないといかなる場合**も**Brain Powerを使用する事ができない状態なのです。

I think that what makes it difficult to understand is that there are two situations (場合 and 状態) and I don't know which one is first. Can I replace も with　は when parsing?

The entire sentence with the translation I got is this:

> > 仮に、契約を延長すればSOUND VOLTEXに今まで通り収録され続ける。逆を言うと、KONAMIから許諾を得ないといかなる場合もBrain Powerを使用する事ができない状態なのです。それは作曲者も同様です。
> >     If I extend the contract, the song would continue to be in SOUND VOLTEX. However to argue that, there may be situations where I am unable to get consent from KONAMI to use Brain Power. As the composer of the song, this would be a big problem for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that from a strictly syntactic view you would get the same parse tree if you replaced も by は, but it would make no sense. This も is part of いかなる場合も (+negative), which means "in no circumstance". Break down the sentence like this

- 逆を言うと、 means "looking at it the other way round" or similar. I don't know enough context to understand exactly what it means - whether supposing that you don't extend the contract, or whether even if you extend you will still not be able to do these various things (over and above the contract provisions). I (and a native speaker very close to me) think that 逆に言うと、is more natural.
- KONAMIから許諾を得ないと is an "if"; meaning "without permission from Konami (whose name in English orthography is not in block capitals).
- いかなる場合も "in whatever case", "in any circumstances whatever"
- Brain Powerを使用する事ができない : use of Brain Power is not possible
- 状態なのです。... "is the situation which obtains"; basically adds no information, but is like saying "This is how it will be if..." at the beginning of the sentence.

Does this help? Is the translation above yours? Because the last sentence isn't really correct either.

Comment: The translation is not mine but thanks for the answer, now I know how to use いかなる場合も